# Binding a value in Blazor with a specific format

Tags: blazor

Is is possible to bind a value in Blazor client in particular format.

For example

```
<input type="text" bind="@TestDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")" />

@code
{
protected DateTime TestDate {get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
}
```

I tried to do

```
<input type="text" bind="@TestDate" format-value="dd.MM.yyyy" />
```

but that didnt do anything, i received a value such as 11/12/2019 1:03:17 PM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's `bind:format`, you have sample in the doc : [Data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#format-strings) paraph **format string**

```cs
<input @bind="StartDate" @bind:format="yyyy-MM-dd" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: I couldnt find it

Comment: Found an updated version of the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#format-strings

Comment: @chrisbyte thx, I updated the link